# Ghosting effect like in bitly.com copy links

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Wondering what library can make this kind of text ghosting animation?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**Fade Out Top**" effect from http://cssanimation.io/ seems pretty similar. You can "absolute" position two layers of your text on top of each other and then run the animation only on one of them to create the "ghost" effect. Here's the original CodePen by cssanimation.io: http://codepen.io/cssanimation/pen/YpPXjR

And here's a fork with the two layers I was suggesting: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVNNGw/

```
<div class="container">
      <h1 class="layer1">cssanimation</h1>
      <h1 class="layer2 cssanimation fadeOutTop">cssanimation</h1>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {overflow: hidden;}
.container { font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; position: relative; height: 300px; } /* center text styling */
h1, .link { font-size: 4.5em; letter-spacing: -4px; font-weight: 700; color: #7e2ea0; text-align: center; } /* h1 styling */
@media screen and (max-width: 488px) { h1 { font-size: 2.6em; letter-spacing: -2px; } } /* control h1 font size below 768px screen */

/* animation duration and fill mode */
.cssanimation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* fadeOutTop animation declaration & iteration counting */
.fadeOutTop { animation-name: fadeOutTop }

/* fadeOutTop animation keyframes */
@keyframes fadeOutTop {
    from { opacity: 1 }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}
.layer1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.layer2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try opening up the web inspector and seeing for yourself how bitly.com does it? Often the best way to learn is by imitating the work of others.

[image]

As you can see it is quite simple. When the user clicks the button, an element is created - the sole purpose of which is to provide the "ghosting" animation that you describe. Then it disappears when the animation is complete.

Comment: @KamelLabiad A library for this specific case? No. A good JavaScript animation library in general would be GreenSock Animation Package. But you could easily accomplish this effect with plain JavaScript and some CSS animation.

Comment: Yes I mean any generic animation library